# Is it possible to use a loop to perform a class method on all of it's type

Tags: c++, class, methods, for-loop, foreach

I'm attempting to write a tile engine and I have a method in one of my classes and I need a way of being able to use one loop to perform the method for all existing instances of the class, for instance if I have a GameObject called tile, and another called enemy would there be a way of calling GameObject::render for both of them without having to specify their names within the loop?

Comment: Do you have a container that contains all those objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some work. For instance in the constructors for your GameObject class you could add a pointer to the GameObject being created to a list. Then in your destructor you could remove the pointer to the object being destroyed from the same list. That way you have a list of pointers to all the live GameObject's which you can loop through whenever you feel the need.

Comment: so I create a vector of the GameObject class, and whenever I add a new GameObject I increase the number of the pointer class and set it to point to anything of the same type I like? like: vector<GameObject> GOPointer; and then whenever I create a new GameObject I pushback the GOPointer and set the latest pointer at the GameObject I just created?

Comment: I think I follow that description, but I'm not certain. However it must be a list (or vector) of pointers, that's very important. You cannot put all the objects you've created on a vector of objects because doing that would create more objects and so you'd get into an infinite loop. Also a vector or list isn't the most efficient way of doing this because the destructor must search through the whole list (or vector) to find the pointer to remove. So you should really do this with a hash_set especially if the number of objects you are creating is large.

Comment: I'm presuming there are no C++ alternatives for a Java hash_map that you might know of?

Comment: C++ has hash_map and hash_set. But they weren't in the previous C++ standard so support for them is often an extension, but I think all major compilers support them one way or another.

Comment: so, I can either use: vector<GameObject*> GOList or a hash_map, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Basically, you're trying to trigger an event for a number of instances of a class.

You'd have an observer class to which you register all instances (possibly in the constructor) of the class you want to notify.

Answer (score 0):

```
class GamePublisher{
public:
   void Attach(GameObject *);
   void Detach(GameObject *);
   void RenderGameObjects();
   static GamePublisher& GetPublisher();
}

void GamePublisher::RenderGameObjects(){
//This is just an example for simplicity, the syntax my be a little off, assuming you have knowledge of functors.
std::for_each(gameObjectContainer.begin(), gameObjectContainer.end(), render_functor);
}

//somewhere else...
class GameObject{
   public:
     virtual void Render()=0;
}

class Tile : public GameObject
{
   public:
     virtual void Render();//your implementation...
     Tile();
}

Tile::Tile() //: member initilizations...{
   GamePublisher::GetPublisher.Attach(this);
}
```

You will have to handle attach/detach and depending on multi-threads will have to come up with or reuse a mechanism for handling this between multiple threads.  Other than that I think this will work for you.  Good luck.

You can handle Detaching from the destructor.